# Is it necessary to use new for dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c, arrays, variable-length-array

In C, we can input the size of an array (at runtime) from the user by the concept of dynamic memory allocation. But we can also use

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n];
```

So what is the need of using pointers for dynamic memory allocation using `new`?

Comment: C doesn't have `new`.

Comment: It all depends. Is the "array" supposed to be returned from a function? Passed to other functions? Where is it declared in relation to the creation/allocation of the array? Do you need to resize it later?

Answer (score 3):

[Variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) came into existence after `C99` standard. Before that, there was no concept for VLA. Please note, moving forward, since `C11`, this has been changed to an *optional* feature.

OTOH, dynamic memory allocation using `malloc()`<sup>##</sup> and family was there from long back.

That said, the VLA is still an *array* and usually, an *array* and a *pointer* are not the same. Array holds type and size information, while a pointer does not have any size information.

Also, FWIW, the array *size* can be defined at *runtime*, but that does not change the *scope* and *lifetime* as compared to *normal* arrays. Just using VLA approach does not change the lifetime of an otherwise *automatic* array to *global* or something else.

---

<sup>**##** There is no `new` keyword in `C`. GLIBC provides [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family of APIs to handle dynamic memory allocation.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

What you have shown is called variable length array supported from C99.

Yes based on the input you are allocating memory. What if you want to extend the allocated memory.

Don't you need pointers now? In order to do `realloc()` . This is one scenario I can think of but we need pointers for dynamic memory allocation.

C doesn't have `new` so my answer is specific to C which has `malloc()` and family functions

If you have a function to allocate memory dynamically say

```
int *alloc_memory()
{
   int n;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   int a[n];
   // Fill values to array and do
   return a;
}
```

Now this will lead to undefined behavior as the allocated memory just has scope of the function. Pointers are useful for this purpose

```
int *alloc_memory()
{
   int n;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
   // Fill values
   return p;
}
```

The point is VLA doesn't provide the flexibility which dynamic memory allocation by pointers provide you.

Answer (score 0):

Using a VLA is conceptually similar to calling `alloca` to allocate automatic mmory.

A few differences between a Variable Length Array (VLA) and dynamically allocated memory using `malloc`:

1) The VLA is an automatic variable that will cease to exist when your function returns.  Whereas dynamically allocated memory with `malloc` will exist until `free` is called or your program exits.

2) For data types other than arrays, such as structs, you probably want allocated with `malloc`.

3) The VLA is typically stored on the stack (although this is not strictly required by the C99 specification), whereas dynamically allocated memory with `malloc` is stored on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing any "*dynamic* memory allocation", i.e. allocation of memory with *dynamic lifetime*. You are using "variable-length arrays" in C99. But it's still a local variable, with "automatic storage duration", which means the variable's lifetime is the scope in which it was declared.